# AngularJS checkbox inside directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

So I have a directive that has a checkbox in it. I need to make a web service call when the value of the checkbox is changed. How can I get the value of that checkbox when it is clicked? I want the checkbox confined to the scope of the directive.

```
myModule.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope:{},
        template:   
            '<div>'+
                '<input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleRoomLock()" name="lockRoom" value="lock" ng-model="lockRoom">'+
            '</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.toggleRoomLock = function(){
                //GET VALUE OF CHECKBOX HERE
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried getting the value using `scope.lockRoom` but I am getting undefined. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to remove the `ng-click` attribute from the template and put a watch on the model. Change the link function to:

```
function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.lockRoom = false; // initialize to unchecked

    scope.$watch('lockRoom', function (value) {
        // value will contain either true or false depending on checked state
    });
}
```

[`$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) allows you to listen to changes on your models (basically objects added to `scope`).

[Example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rmj2DGeNX2eu4PIINoFf?p=preview) (value logged to console).

Comment: So i just tried what you suggested and it's not triggering the $watch when i click.

Comment: Compare it with the plunker I added. If you still can't get it to work please create a plunker and I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the value of `scope.lockRoom` from your toggle function:

```
'<input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggle()" ng-model="lockRoom">'
...
scope.toggle = function() {
   console.log('lockRoom=',scope.lockRoom)
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xlcLpt7JGn6S0Crgyndi?p=preview)

However, `ng-change` is usually used with checkboxes, rather than `ng-click`:

```
'<input type="checkbox" ng-change="toggle()" ng-model="lockRoom">'
```

Using `ng-change` or `ng-click` may be more efficient than using `$watch`, since the `toggle()` function will not be called every digest cycle, like the `$watch` is.